# C++ Loading an Icon on to a Button

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to load an icon on to my button. I'm using Code::Blocks. I really
don't care whether the image is a BITMAP (.bmp) or an ICON (.ico). Here's the code I have below for case WM_CREATE.

```
case WM_CREATE:
    HWND button;
    button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "My Button", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                          225, 225, 100, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
break;
```

Is it possible to add an icon to a button without it getting very complicated? Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send a `BM_SETIMAGE` message to your button like this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
  // load your bitmap from the executable, you should also be able
  // to load the bitmap / or icon from disk using `LoadImage`
  HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE("<ResourceID>"));

  // notice the BS_BITMAP flag (you could also use `BS_ICON`)
  // perhaps you also would like to add BS_PUSHBUTTTON style
  HWND button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", 
                             "My Button", 
                             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP,
                             225, 225, 100, 25, 
                             hwnd, 
                             NULL, 
                             hInstance, 
                             NULL);
  // set the bitmap of your window, you could use `BM_SETICON` in
  // case you're using an icon rather than a bitmap
  SendMessage(button, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
break;
```

To load a bitmap from a file on disk you could do something like this:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, 
                                     "NameOfBitmap.bmp", 
                                     IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                     0, 0,
                                     LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

**References**
[Button Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[LoadBitmap()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[LoadIcon()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[LoadImage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Button Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Note you can also do this with icons using `BS_ICON` in the button window style bits, `IMAGE_ICON` in the `BM_SETIMAGE` message-send, and an `HICON` for the `LPARAM` of said-same.

Comment: heh, that'll teach m to read code and not comments. uptick btw. nice answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was easy to understand AND it worked :D

Comment: Do you know how to also add text on to the button? For some reason my text is invisible :(

Comment: @SquigglyMuffinMan - Have you tried using `SetWindowText(hwnd, "<text>");`?

Comment: No I haven't I probably should have. Thanks for answering though :)